# Update the value for key inside the JSON in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have JSON with a similar structure in MySQL database.

```
{
  "name": "Signature",
  "key": "Signature",
  "children": [
   {
     "name": "Signature",
     "key": "Signature"
   },
   {
     "name": "SignerUUID",
     "key": "SignerUUID"
   }
  ]
}
```

I want to update the value against the name field inside the children JSON for key Signature like below

```
{
  "name": "Signature",
  "key": "Signature",
  "children": [
   {
     "name": "SignHere",
     "key": "Signature"
   },
   {
     "name": "SignerUUID",
     "key": "SignerUUID"
   }
  ]
}
```

How can I update the above value in an efficient way?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Why store in JSON though? It isn't in 1 NF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your sample data, you can use `JSON_SEARCH` to find the child whose `name` is `Signature`, and then use `JSON_REPLACE` to replace the value. Something like this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET json_column = JSON_REPLACE(json_column, 
                               JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(json_column, 'one', 'Signature', NULL, '$.children[*].name')),
                               'SignHere')
```